# Как сделать поиск по всем файлам репозитория в gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

Есть репозиторий, в котором проект с множеством файлов.
Как мне сделать поиск по всему репозиторию, чтобы поиск произошел в каждом файле?

Видел, что так делают, но самому подобный интерфейс найти не удалось.

Comment: Прямо в репозитории есть кнопка "FInd file", ее недостаточно? Она игнорирует пути и показывает все файлы (но вместе с путями)

Comment: @AidarSaifutdinov это кнопка ищет файлы, а мне необходимо выполнить поиск по их содержимому

Comment: Попробуй в поиске просто ввести код, там откроется поиск по коду, у меня сработало!

Comment: @AidarSaifutdinov получилось, спасибо большое!